# How to access variables in for-loop

Tags: java, variables, object, for-loop, java.util.scanner

I'm scanning in numbers and names using the scanner in a `for-loop`. How can I access these variables and use the contents within them outside of the `for-loop`? Or is there no possible way?

```
       for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
       {
           int height = scanner.nextInt();
           int weight = scanner.nextInt();
           String name = scanner.nextLine();
       }
```

Comment: You were given the answer 40 min ago in a question you deleted!

Comment: @AndersonGreen he deleted it and asked it again. I don't know what games he's playing with us, but if it's ignore or erase the efforts of others, I want no part in it.

Comment: The last post I had instantiated an object within the for-loop and tried to call a method for that object outside of it. I deleted the post cause I was unaware I could edit my code/question. @HovercraftFullOfEels

Comment: The answer is the same.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels by no means was I trying to undermine others efforts.

Answer (score 1):

Create the variables outside the for-loop. Then you can access them from outside. Just read about the scopes of variables in java. [This](http://www.java-made-easy.com/variable-scope.html) is a good one to read.

```
int height, weight;
String name;

for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++){
    height = scanner.nextInt();
    weight = scanner.nextInt();
    name = scanner.nextLine();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

please do not limit the scope of the variables, to for loop, if you want to use it outside, probably you should declare the reference of outside and initialize within the for loop.